# Averaging of curves with 95% shade

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data,

```
Data = data.frame(Participant = rep(sprintf("part%03d", 1:100), each=100),
                  Group = rep(c(0,1), each=5*1e3),
                  Evidence = rnorm(1e4),
                  CorrectOrNot = c(rbinom(5*1e3, size=1, prob=.3),
                                   rbinom(5*1e3, size=1, prob=.6)))
```

where "Participant" is the index for each participant, "Group" the condition each participant is assigned to, "Evidence" the 'strength' of stimulus to each participant, and "CorrectOrNot" the correctedness of the answer to each stimulus of each participants.

So I have conducted the logistic regression for each participant, about the relationship between Evidence and probability of Correct answer.

---

```
plot(1, type="n", xlab="Evidence", ylab="probCorrect", 
     xlim=c(-3, 3), ylim=c(0, 1))

for (i in 1:100)
{
  part = sprintf("part%03d", i)
  test = Data[Data$Participant==part,]

  fit = glm(CorrectOrNot ~ Evidence, test, family=binomial)
  newDat = data.frame(Evidence=seq(min(test$Evidence),max(test$Evidence),len=100))
  newDat$pc = predict(fit, newdata=newDat, type="response")

  lines(pc ~ Evidence, newDat, col=ifelse(test$Group[1]==0, "green", "red"), lwd=2)
}

legend(-3, 1, legend=c("Group 0", "Group 1"),
       col=c("green", "red"), lty=1:2, cex=0.6)
```

To visualize the resulting curves, I have written the above code, where the result seems quite messy. So I would like to "average" the lines into two representative lines from each group, with some shade around them representing 95% "range" of each group.

Any help, including one using `ggplot2`, will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **tidyverse** package (which also includes ggplot2) can help us reorganize your code a little. For example, rather than an explicit loop, we can conduct a series of operations for each unique value of the Participant column:

```
library(tidyverse)

newDat2 <- Data %>% 
  nest(-Participant) %>% 
  mutate(
    smoothDat = map(data, function(x) data.frame(Group = x$Group[1], Evidence=seq(min(x$Evidence),max(x$Evidence),len=100))),
    fit = map(data, function(x) glm(CorrectOrNot ~ Evidence, x, family=binomial)),
    predict = map2(smoothDat, fit, function(s, f) {
      s$pc <- predict(f, newdata = s, type = 'response')
      return(s)
    })
  )
```

In the call to `mutate`, "smoothDat" creates the data used for generating the prediction, "fit" calculates the model for each participant, and finally, "predict" contains the returned predictions. Finally, we unnest "predict":

```
newDat2 <- unnest(newDat2, predict)

   Participant Group Evidence    pc
   <fct>       <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1 part001         0    -2.47 0.215
 2 part001         0    -2.42 0.215
 3 part001         0    -2.37 0.216
 4 part001         0    -2.32 0.217
 5 part001         0    -2.27 0.217
 6 part001         0    -2.22 0.218
 7 part001         0    -2.17 0.219
 8 part001         0    -2.12 0.219
 9 part001         0    -2.07 0.220
10 part001         0    -2.02 0.221
# ... with 9,990 more rows
```

To get a data set for all your participants that is compatible with ggplot2.

From there, the plotting code is relatively easy. I'm using `geom_smooth` to calculate a summary for each Group. There are lots of options to play with there.

```
plot.newdat <- ggplot(data = newDat2, aes(x = Evidence, y = pc, color = factor(Group), group = Participant)) +
  geom_line(alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_smooth(aes(group = Group), method = glm, method.args = list(family = binomial))
print(plot.newdat)
```

[image]